# Can I create folder on SQL Server Reporting Services using store procedure

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2019

i possible create new folder using gui method. Is it possible create new folder using mssql stored procedure?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, the folders are just entries in the `catalog` table.

The code below works but you might not need everything shown here.

You can turn this script into an SP easily, it requires three parameters to be set.

1. @FolderName - the name of the folder you want to create
2. @UserName - The name of the user you want to show as the creating user
3. @PolicyID - This relates (I think) to security, so I took this value from an existing folder that has the same security as the folder I wanted to create

Here's the script

```
DECLARE @FolderName varchar(75) = 'My Test Folder'
DECLARE @UserName varchar(75) = 'Joe.Bloggs'
DECLARE @PolicyID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '7e032071-6e30-46ab-9600-e0cc0a7adcf0' -- Taken from an existing folder with required permission

-- Get root folder
DECLARE @RootItemID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (SELECT ItemID FROM [Catalog] WHERE Type = 1 and Path = '')
-- Get creation User
DECLARE @UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (SELECT UserID FROM [Users] WHERE UserName = @UserName)

INSERT INTO [Catalog] ([ItemID], [Path], [Name], [ParentID], [Type], [Content], [Intermediate], [SnapshotDataID], [LinkSourceID], [Property], [Description], [Hidden], [CreatedByID], [CreationDate], [ModifiedByID], [ModifiedDate], [MimeType], [SnapshotLimit], [Parameter], [PolicyID], [PolicyRoot], [ExecutionFlag], [ExecutionTime], [SubType], [ComponentID])
SELECT 
  [ItemID] = NEWID()
, [Path] = '/' + @FolderName
, [Name] = @FolderName
, [ParentID] = @RootItemID
, [Type] = 1
, [Content] = NULL
, [Intermediate] = NULL
, [SnapshotDataID] = NULL
, [LinkSourceID] = NULL
, [Property] = '<Properties />'
, [Description] = NULL
, [Hidden] = 0
, [CreatedByID] = @UserID
, [CreationDate] = getdate()
, [ModifiedByID] = @UserID
, [ModifiedDate] = getdate()
, [MimeType] = NULL
, [SnapshotLimit] = NULL
, [Parameter] = NULL
, [PolicyID] = @PolicyID
, [PolicyRoot] = 1
, [ExecutionFlag] = 1
, [ExecutionTime] = NULL
, [SubType] = NULL
, [ComponentID] = NULL
```